# Replace properties in one file from those in another in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb

I want to replace properties in one file from those in another. (I am new to ruby, and read about Ruby and YAML. I have a Java background)

Eg.

**File 1**

```
server_ip_address=$[ip]
value_threshold=$[threshold]
system_name=$[sys_name]
```

**File 2**

```
ip=192.168.1.1
threshold=10
sys_name=foo
```

The ruby script should replace the $ values by their real values (I do not know if $[] is the format used in ruby. Also do Files 1 and 2 have to be YAML files, or erb files?) and produce File 1 as :

```
server_ip_address=192.168.1.1
value_threshold=10
system_name=foo
```

I searched the web for this, but could not express it in the right keywords to find a solution/pointer to a solution/reference material on google. How can this be done by a ruby script?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an arbitrary template format you've invented, or is it something you've inherited? In ERB this is done with `<%= ip %>` as an example. In YAML you'd define variables like `ip: 192.168.1.1`.

Comment: As I said in my question, "I do not know if $[] is the format used in ruby. Also do Files 1 and 2 have to be YAML files, or erb files?"

Comment: They don't have to be anything, but it would be easier if file 1 was ERB and file 2 was YAML. That you didn't know if it was used in Ruby wasn't an explanation as to where this came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can switch the formats, this should be as easy as:

```
require 'yaml'

variables = YAML.load(File.open('file2.yaml'))
template = File.read('file1.conf')

puts template.gsub(/\$\[(\w+)\]/) { variables[$1] }
```

Your template can stay as-is, but the substitution file would look like:

```
ip: 192.168.1.1
threshold: 10
sys_name: foo
```

This makes it easy to read in using the YAML library.

Comment: Your script before you made an edit gave the following error
`/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in \`eval': wrong argument type Array (expected Binding) (TypeError)
 from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in \`result'
 from abcd.rb:5:in \`<main>'`

Here abcd.rb is the file into which I put the ruby script

Comment: Can you please post the earlier (without the edit) script (after correcting it), since i'd like to use the erb format.

Comment: The down-side to the ERB format, and why I removed it, was due to how you need to have local variables defined. This is considerably more awkward than simply referencing a Hash. The [ERB documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) shows several examples. Creating arbitrary local variables from a YAML file is a recipe for trouble later.