# Replacing variable value in ruby while setting the value using "set" command

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a .properties files as below:

```
user:abcd
pwd:xyz
system:test
```

Next, I have a ruby script with Watir for browser automation. In this script, I have statements like

```
browser.text_field(:id => 'identifierId').set "#{user}:variable to be replaced by its value from .properties file".
```

Similarly, other values need to be replaced for "pwd" and "system".

I tried the solution per below posts:
[Replace properties in one file from those in another in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974663/replace-properties-in-one-file-from-those-in-another-in-ruby)

However, "set" command is setting whatever has been paased as arguments to it instead of replacing the variable with its value.

Please help.

Comment: Not really clear on what you are trying to do. Can you give an example of what you want to happen? Is it just that you want to change some of the key vals in the file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the information out of the file.
Most Watir users leverage yaml files for this.

`config/properties.yml`:

```
user: abcd
pwd: xyz
system: test
```

Then read the yaml file & parse your data:

```
properties = YAML.safe_load(IO.read('config/properties.yml'))

text_field = browser.text_field(id: 'identifierId')
text_field.set properties['user']
```

Alternately you can take a look at [Cheezy's Fig Newton gem](https://github.com/cheezy/fig_newton), which is designed to work with his Page Object gem

Comment: This is exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you.